# How do I connect two nodes in a network graph and print out the path?

Tags: r

I'm trying print out the connecting path of two non-adjacent nodes in a network graph. For instance, I have A connecting to B connecting to C, and A and C are not connected; between each connections is a label for the edge. I want a printout of point A to point C: A (edge label) B (edge label) C. I am trying to do this in R. Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. I assume you are using `igraph`?

Comment: use igraph packgage

Comment: I like the `DiagrammeR` package.

Comment: You mean you want a text summary of the network graph?